# How to create and open many files using c program ? (say n files)

Tags: c, file, fopen, ulimit

I need to know how to create many empty files and open them simultaneously using a c program.

Comment: Read `fopen` and use it.

Comment: IF you know how to create one file using C, you can then combine the concept of `for-loop` to create n files having file names with changing suffix e.g. file01, file02, fileN ....

Comment: `Need to know`...Good. `(implicit) Did not try anything myself`...Bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE *fp[n];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  fp=fopen("filename","mode");

  /*Do What you want with these files....*/

  fclose(fp);
}
```